# Space between Field Output Label and Field input

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have to increase space between Field Label(output text value) &  Field input box.

{https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X79S.png}

Space between Name Label and Field input box

I am using JSF 2.2.

Comment: Images can be embedded in questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow. Preferably you can include more code to help others answer your question.

Comment: google "css padding & margin"

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a h:panelgrid and if you need more space between you labels and your inputs just add style in te panelgrid modifying the css of the panlegrid